# How would one go about blocking websites on a home network with the latest versions of Linux and programs like SQUID?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy

(EDIT 2018-08-02: Someone asked about how "not easy" the setup below should be to defeat. It should be at least as "not easy" as accessing a computer or feature to which you do not have the password, even if you have root access and full control over your client machine. That would suffice for this purpose. THIS IS STILL AN ACTIVE REQUEST.)

I'm curious about this. It concerns a situation I have regarding website blocking that I haven't been able to find much information on as it and the combination of both the specific network setup and usage requirements seem to be somewhat peculiar given all the postings I've seen about similar questions which have proved aggravatingly insufficient and I really don't know what to do. I've been trying for the last half megasecond or so to try and set up a system at my home to block access to problematic websites that I tend to frequent so that they will be less bothersome for me and my work and there will not be as much temptation to want to browse them, and it seems to be rather more difficult than I thought it first was - VERY difficult indeed.

The basic setup that I have is that the computers in the house form a wireless network which connects to a wireless router, which in turn connects to the Internet through a cable modem, including the computer I use. I had been using a solution where that computer, which runs Linux Mint, had had installed a simple block through /etc/hosts (redirect the URLs of the sites to something like 127.0.0.1 so the browser chokes) and that was working; but the problem is, of course, it was and is too easy for me to get in there and disable it as it's just a root terminal away, so what I came up with was to have someone else in the home whom I trust set their own ROOT password so I can't access that file. Trouble with that is, I often need to load software onto the machine which needs root access, and there's the (hasn't yet happened but still there) possibility to use a different computer in the house to surf away to my heart's content on those problematic websites.

So what I thought of instead was to insert a computer that we had not been using in between the cable modem and the wireless router to intercept and filter the traffic, and then have THAT machine passworded up so I can't get at it, at least not easily enough to make the sites so readily available. And what I decided on was to install Ubuntu on it and found a program called "SQUID" that is supposed to act as a "proxy server" which lets you send traffic through it and filter/remove the stuff you don't want, among other things. But I've been having a heck of a time trying to block those problematic social media sites (Quora, Reddit, and maybe others) with this thing. (This part does not seem like an uncommon complaint, what seems uncommon is the *combination* of this particular network setup and the requirement that it not be easy to disable or work around the block, at least not something you can just do with a few seconds at a terminal or hunting through browser settings. It doesn't have to be world-class secure, just enough to dissuade "easy fixes".)

But it's been proving very difficult to do and it seems the crux of the problem is all these modern websites, including of course these huge social media platforms, use (rather sensibly) HTTPS, and you can't apparently easily block that with a proxy - at least, not the kind of "transparent" proxy that this is which allows you to avoid having to configure it in a browser (problem with that is, well, I can just click off the proxy and voila! The sites are now ready to cook!). What I seem to have so far is two options and they don't seem entirely satisfactory:

1. One option is apparently that newer versions of SQUID can use a "man-in-the-middle" kind of filtering of secure HTTPS connection. It looks like it may be possible to set this up, but again I can't find any information tailored to this specific use case nor that is really up-to-date, i.e. as of the last few tens of megaseconds (year 2018 or so) and software and systems date fast, something I'm really appreciating with this project. Worse, I've heard some ominous warnings that there may even be legal issues (I'm in USA) with doing this kind of thing - which is understandable given you're effectively snooping on secure traffic, although of course my intention isn't to read anyone's private messages or data but just to obstruct certain websites altogether, but nonetheless that may still run afoul somehow. And I definitely don't want to get a funny visit from FBI followed by a courtroom appearance and *I lack the money to afford a lawyer to get legal counsel on this, big time*. So that seems essentially dead.
2. The other option is rather more prosaic. Since the "opaque"(?) proxy *does* block the sites, just force everyone's browser to use the server by dropping port 443 traffic on the filtering machine. This would be much less risky/questionable, but nonetheless would create a bit of inconvenience/hassle for others in my household, though perhaps they would be okay with it. Just not sure.

What I'd really be after is if there's a third option I've missed here somehow that might be able to deal with this. As said, I've never found anything addressing something quite like this. Wanting to block troublesome social media sites is nothing new, but usually it seems what is suggested amounts to a more casual block where that the browser settings alone are sufficient deterrent. For the author of this question, they aren't.

So what is the best way to go about achieving the aim here - if not through SQUID or even this setup, then something else? What's the optimal solution?

Comment: When you say you don't want it to be "easy" to get around this filtering, how easy do you mean? What is the technical ability of the people using this network? There are simple fixes (make your router primary DNS and point its internal DNS to an online filtering service such as OpenDNS) that are "easily" counteracted given a bit of Googling. And there are complex methods (attempting to capture all DNS requests and route them to and through your internal proxy.

Comment: The main difference between the simple and the complex is the number of work-arounds you actively block in the process.

Comment: @music2myear : See edit at top.

Comment: Pfsense 2.3.x has everything you need to do this in the package manager. Go with either dansguardian or squidproxy. If you just want to straight up no-frills block something you create an alias for the domain ips then a blocking rule.